# OAuth Login Flow: How to create users on my own backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We have a web app that caters to a small set of users that are guaranteed to have an account on Office 365.

To save them from remembering one more password, and to use Microsoft's infrastructure for OAuth, we decided to allow them to login using their Outlook credentials.

It is a react app, we are using the `msal` library and we have successfully been able to receive the accessToken from Microsoft. (Thus, authenticating the user's identity.)

What I am not confused about now is what I should do with that token:

1. I need to have my own User database. What information should I store in it? Should I store the access_token as well?
2. How do I verify the user's identity on my backend server?

Basically, what is the ideal way of managing this kind of a scenario? Wherein a third party authenticator is used (and solely) used to confirm the identity of the user and get the name, profile image and other things only.

Any references to existing workflows or an explanation of the steps involved will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does Office365 adds the OpenID profile of the user to it's response (I think it is when you first get the access token)?

Comment: It does. It does return the basic info I need.

Comment: If i want to access their complete profile, I have to make a GET Request to the Graph endpoint with that access token.

Comment: But is seems you don't need to, Just create the user with the info you receive from the OpenID. They dont need to create a password etc, it is all happening in the backend.